# Creating an array of objects to be added to another object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a discord bot and I'm trying to format an object to be sent to their API to result in a neatly organized message.
In short this is what i'm trying to do:

```
var entries = [];

entries.push({
    name: item.title + " - " + item.link,
    value: text,
    inline: true
});

msg.channel.sendMessage("", {
    embed: {
        title: url,
        description: "",
        fields: entries,
        color: 0
    }
});
```

What happens is, when i push a few of those objects to `entries` and print it to the console it displays a totally valid array of objects. But by adding this array into the embed objects the result is empty. The array isn't added.

To be more specific, the issue is not converting it to a string resolvable, but the issue is that:

```
let test = { 
    embed: {
        title: url,
        description: "",
        fields: entries,
        color: 0
    }
};
console.log(test);
```

When i try to put the array `entries` into the fields the result is when printed: fields: [], meaning that the objects added to `entries` (which when printed is properly filled) don't get added to fields in the embed.

```
fields: entries,
```

turns out to be

```
fields: [],
```

Comment: What are the arguments for `sendMessage` method?

Comment: should fields be string?

Comment: To be more specific, the issue is not converting it to a string resolvable, but the issue is that: 

`let test = { 
  embed: {
   title: url,
   description: "",
   fields: entries.toString(),
   color: 0
  }
 };
 console.log(test);`

When i try to put the json array `entries` into the `fields` the result is when printed:

`fields: []`

Comment: Could you try `console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 2))` and check if it still shows empty?

Comment: You're dealing with javascript objects here.  There is no JSON.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(test, null, 2));`
Will keep `fields: [],`.